# trying to print only 15 lines hesitate print 15 more. 

Tags: java

I am trying to only print 15 lines at a time, pause then print 15 more.

Thank you for your time.

```
for (int month = 0; month < amorization.length; month++) {      
    System.out.println ("\0\0"+ (int)amorization[month][0] + "\t\t" + df.format(amorization[month][1])+"\t\t" + df.format(amorization[month][2])+"\t\t\t"+ df.format(amorization[month][3])+ "\t\t\t" +df.format(amorization[month][4])); 
}
```

Comment: You'd keep a counter to see how many lines you've printed out. Every time the counter hits a multiple of 15, you'd do your sleep. The `month` variable you're using for this could be used for this, since it's a simple incrementing integer (right?). So `if (month % 15 = 0) { sleep(...); }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the for loop, you can add this condition

```
if(month%15 == 0){
     Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
for (int month = 0; month < amorization.length; month++)
{       
    System.out.println ("\0\0"+ (int)amorization[month][0] + "\t\t" + df.format(amorization[month][1])+"\t\t" + df.format(amorization[month][2])+"\t\t\t"+ df.format(amorization[month][3])+ "\t\t\t" +df.format(amorization[month][4])); 

    if (month % 15 == 0) {
        Thread.sleep(sometime);
    }
}
```

Comment: ahhhh i knew it was easy ... i have been at it for a few hours now thank you or your help !

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

public class SimpleTest {

```
    @Test
    public void testHello() throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.print();
    }
}

class Foo {
    public void print() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int month = 0; month < 100; month++) {
            System.out.println("Foo");
            if(month % 15 == 0) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
  for (int month = 0; month < amorization.length; month++)
  {       
    if ( i % 15 == 0 ) {
      Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
  }

  System.out.println ((int)amorization[month][0] + "\t\t" + df.format(amorization[month][1])+"\t\t" +     df.format(amorization[month][2])+"\t\t\t"+ df.format(amorization[month][3])+ "\t\t\t" +df.format(amorization[month][4]));

 }
}
catch(InterruptedException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

also no need for \0 \0 because it do nothing!